# Calculate Average in JavaScript when there is missing value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a row of 10 cells in which user enters the value.
I need to calculate the average of only those cells which has value and ignore the cells without value.
I take the input using document.getElementById("demo").value and then insert it in an array.
In case of missing value it is inserting 0 in the array which I don't want.

```
var calcvalue = new array();
for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
   var getObj = document.getElementById('demo'+ i);
   if(getObj.value != ''){
      calcvalue.push(getObj.value);
      break;
  }
}
```

How can I ignore the cells which don't have any value.

Comment: Please provide the HTML.

Comment: so, change *your code* such that in case of missing value, don't insert ANYTHING into the array - et voila - problem solved

Comment: I am trying value != ' ';
array.push(value);

But it is inserting 0 in this case too.

Comment: yes, that's a start .. but `value !=''` doesn't do anything useful except result in a boolean that is true if the value is not an empty string - what do you do with this boolean result?

Comment: I see, because you're simply doing `value != ''` ignoring the result, an pushing the value regardless of the previous code which has no effect on the push

Comment: I am using this value != ' ' under 'if condition'.
So, my code is like
if (value != ' '){
   array.push(value);
}

Comment: By inserting 0, you are affecting the average. What you need is don't insert anything at all. You said you've tried it, but it still inserts a 0, in which case I can only speculate that you are doing something wrong. Without seeing the code, nobody can answer what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @vanowm Yes exactly, But it is inserting 0 on it own. I want to know the way to prevent it.

Comment: Well, provide a sample so we can evaluate what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @vanowm i have added sample code

Comment: Loop through your array and ignore the zeros, so: if (item != 0) process() and make sure your item count excludes the items with zeros as well when calculating the average

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code there could be many different reasons why it doesn't work for you.
Perhaps this will gives you an idea how to fix it:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("test");
form.addEventListener("input", e =>
{
  const array = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < form.length; i++)
  {
    if (form[i].value !== "") //only include fields with value. 0 considered as accepted value
      array.push(Number(form[i].value)); //make sure we insert a number, not string
  }
  document.getElementById("res").textContent = array.length ? array.reduce((a,b)=>a+b) / array.length : "";
});
```

```html
average: <span id="res"></span>
<form id="test">
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
  <div><input type="number"></div>
</form>
```

[EDIT]
Your code works fine without `break` (and it should be `new Array()` with a capital "A")

```js
const form = document.getElementById("test");
form.addEventListener("input", e =>
{
  var calcvalue = new Array();
  for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
     var getObj = document.getElementById('demo'+ i);
     if(getObj.value != ''){
        calcvalue.push(getObj.value);
//        break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("res").textContent = JSON.stringify(calcvalue);
});
```

```html
array: <span id="res"></span>
<form id="test">
  <div><input id="demo0" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo1" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo2" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo3" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo4" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo5" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo6" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo7" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo8" type="number"></div>
  <div><input id="demo9" type="number"></div>
</form>
```

Also note, that you are adding a string into array, so during your average calculation you'll need convert each value into a number